# AS3 : accessing variable value

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

I have on stage 3 buttons every button should play a sound ... i'm trying to

make the class code dynamic .But i'm stuck with a problem please see the code .

i need help ! [fla link](http://www.filedropper.com/test_34) & [class link](http://www.filedropper.com/custumclass)

i want to get the String inside the variable not only the name .

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class CustumClass extends MovieClip
    {
    private var R1:String ="im a string inside R1";
    private var R2:String ="im a string inside R2";
    private var R3:String  = "im a string inside R3";

    private var btns:Array;
    private var link:String;

        public function CustumClass()
        {
            // constructor code
            btns = new Array(r1,r2,r3);  //___ buttons on stage
            onLoop();

        }
        private function onLoop():void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i<btns.length; i++)
            {
                btns[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleBtn);
            }
        }

        private function handleBtn(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // ____ i want to get the string inside variable 

            link = e.target.name.toUpperCase();
            trace (link);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your buttons in an `Array`

```
private var btns:Array;
```

use a [`Dictionary`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html)

```
private var buttons:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
```

Then add each reference to a button along with the `String` that you want to associate with it

```
// constructor code

buttons[r1] = "text for r1";
buttons[r2] = "text for r2";
buttons[r3] = "text for r3";

onLoop();
```

You can iterate over the keys.

```
private function onLoop():void
{
    for (var button:Object in buttons)
    {
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleBtn);

        // if above fails, try something like
        IEventListener(button).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleBtn);
    }
}
```

You can retrieve a value with a key

```
private function handleBtn(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace (buttons[e.currentTarget]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you your code work like charm . i just to know if existe other way to make the code work using array

Comment: @AyoubHit Choose a tool according to the job, not the other way round. You can do this with an `Array` but it makes little to no sense to do it this way. Don't force a solution with an `Array` onto the problem. Your best bet would be to use neither `Array` nor `Dictionary`, but to define a class for your buttons. this way you don't need the data structures to create the association from one button to a `String` because each button knew its own `String`.

Comment: Thanks alot .I understand what you mean